# Is it possible to z-index divs at different levels?

Tags: html, css, z-index

That is to say, if I had the following:

```
<div id="a">
    <div id="b"></div>
</div>
<div id="c"></div>
```

Would it be possible for me to visually place b beneath c without putting a beneath c? I'm thinking the answer is no but I was curious if there was some css trickery I was unaware of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible. b and a are going to be indexed "together" as a group, and the c will be calculated separately. see http://jsfiddle.net/73KXM/

Answer (score 0):

If you did, `b` would also be behind `a` and thus not visible.

Answer (score 0):

```
#a {
     z-index: 50;
}

#b {
     z-index: 0;
}

#c {
     z-index: 25;
}
```

Of course, if #b is entirely contained within #a (no negative margins, etc.), it wouldn't be seen.  If you're looking for a sort of circular z-index, I don't think it can be done.  You may need to break a div into pieces and "fake" it.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is.
If you want to use z-index, you have to set the position to relative.